# Не работает hover с разными параметрами одновременно к 5 элементам?

Tags: hover

```css
.main:hover {
      background: white;
      color:  #A1BAD8;
}
.main:hover .circle:hover  {
   background:  #A1BAD8;
}
.main:hover h3:hover {
  color:  white;
}
.main:hover p:hover,
.main:hover h2:hover, 
.main:hover .read:hover {
  color:  #A1BAD8;
}
```

```html
  <div class="main"> 
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="circle"> <h3> A. </h3> </div>
    <h2> Money Saving Ideas</h2>
    <p> Praesent vestibulum<br> aenean nonummy hendrerit mauris. Curn sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis.</p>
    <p> <a href="#" class="read"> read more </a> </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Что означает «не работает»? Поведение вас чем-то не устраивает?

Comment: При наведении мыши работает сразу только первый ховер - .main:hover. А остальные ховеры работают только, если попасть по ним мышкой отдельно на каждый блок

Comment: а какой должен? какое поведение вы вообще ожидаете получить?

Comment: @Алина неправда, не только. При наведении на `A.` срабатывает второй .circle:hover и третий h3:hover, при наведении на `read more` срабатывает последний .read:hover — всё в точности с написанными в стилях селекторами

Comment: Смена цветов на противоположные одновременно во всех блоках при наведении мыши. С родительскими и дочерними элементами почему-то не работает((Что-то я делаю не так

Comment: Уточню, что я имею в виду - необходимо, чтобы ховеры срабатывали одновременно при наведении на main

Comment: Ну значит и пишите все нужные вам изменения именно для `.main:hover`. Если же вы написали `.circle:hover` и прочую дребедень, то вполне логично, что они будут срабатывать только при ховере на эти конкретные элементы

Comment: Я не могу написать это все в один ховер, там стили, которые противоречат друг другу (прямо противоположные цвета), но необходимо, чтобы они все срабатывали одновременно. Возможно как-то по-другому написать стили ховера для  родителя и потомков, чтобы они срабатывали одновременно? Я пропустила эту тему (родитель/потомок) и теперь не улавливаю в чём проблема

Comment: Вы можете написать это с одним ховером, никто не говорил про один селектор. То есть `.main:hover .circle {...}` и `.main:hover h3 {...}` и так далее

Comment: Спасибо! Пошла пробовать!

Comment: Всё работает! Еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Всё работает. Вы так хотели?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>hover</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .main:hover {
      background-color: white;
      color:  #A1BAD8;
    }
    .main:hover a {
      background-color: white;
      color:  #A1BAD8;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main"> 
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="circle"> <h3> A. </h3> </div>
    <h2> Money Saving Ideas</h2>
    <p> Praesent vestibulum<br> aenean nonummy hendrerit mauris. Curn sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis.</p>
    <p> <a href="#" class="read"> read more </a> </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Всё решилось!